# Is everything in Emacs made of functions?

Tags: functions

Being more used to Vim, I know that it was correct to think "everything in Vim is a macro" but what about Emacs?

Is it fine/correct to think that everything is a function in Emacs?

Comment: The question is too broad, and so should be closed IMO. "Function" has zillions of meanings in math, computer science, and programming. Can someone say that everything in the universe is a function or can be modeled by a function? Sure. And? Certainly everything in Emacs Lisp is not a function *as defined by the language*. Not everything satisfies `functionp`, for example, or `funcall`. If there is a useful, specific question here about Elisp, please rephrase to make clear what that is.

Comment: Sorry, didn't meant to make this as broad as it was :/ i mean, it's mostly just a meta question about Emacs so, that does make it more specific than talking about it's "zillions of meanings in math, computer science, and programming" :)

It's just a saying i heard many times before, and doubted how correct it was...

Comment: Maybe you want to change the question to ask whether everything in Elisp satisfies predicate `functionp`? But that has an easy answer - if everything satisfied it then it would have no reason to exist. Any way you look at it, your question is too broad or unclear, even if interpretation is limited to what Elisp _calls_ a function. And we don't know what you mean by "function" wrt Elisp, in your question.

Comment: followed your recommendation and changed the question to something more specific

Comment: Every key sequence you type is bound to something.

Comment: The question is now somewhat different to what it was when it was answered.  I realise the edit was made in good faith, but I'm not sure it was for the best at this point?  In particular, the accepted answer doesn't match as well as it did originally -- if we're now only asking about "the majority" rather than "everything" then it's pretty redundant to be pointing out the there are some things which aren't functions.  FWIW, the question I *thought* you were asking was something like "Does every interactive action call a function?", and my answer doesn't fit any other question terribly well.

Comment: Yeah, guess i'll revert it to the old question then! just thought it would follow @Drew suggestion, even if it was already answered as you mentioned phils

Comment: My suggestion is to delete the question. Or ask a question that fits the existing answers, as they've been voted as useful.

Comment: would reverting back to the old question fit? I mean i wouldn't mind (especially since they've been voted as useful and were successfully answered too) @Drew

Comment: Not in my opinion. It was to the original question that I commented that it was too broad. @phils's answer posits that your question is _really_ meaning to ask whether *every interactive user action* invokes a function. That's a specific question, and it's very different from anything you've asked. If you ask that one then it fits phils's answer.

Comment: But it doesn't fit @gigiair's answer. Take your pick - pose a specific question that fits one of the answers. Or delete the question altogether. Those are my suggestions - just one opinion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not *everything* is a function, no.  For starters, Elisp (the language) has many other kinds of object besides functions.

However, I think you're specifically asking whether every *interactive* action from the user is invoking a function behind the scenes; and the answer is still no.

The majority of commands will be functions; but not all of them.

Quoting from <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Interactive Call`:

> Commands include strings and vectors (which are treated as keyboard
> macros), lambda expressions that contain a top-level ‘interactive’
> form (*note Using Interactive::), byte-code function objects made
> from such lambda expressions, autoload objects that are declared as
> interactive (non-‘nil’ fourth argument to ‘autoload’), and some
> primitive functions.  Also, a symbol is considered a command if it
> has a non-‘nil’ ‘interactive-form’ property, or if its function
> definition satisfies ‘commandp’.

Comment: Didn't knew! I guess this should be the accepted answer, but I'm glad i learned this :)

Comment: @NordineLotfi if you like this better than my answer, you should absolutely change your pick. You can change your vote anytime, and you should when a better answer comes along!

Comment: Aren't all of these things still functions/macros, just in different forms?  e.g. a byte-code object is a compiled representation of a function, autoload objects only wrap functions/macros, symbols with an 'interactive-form' property must reference a function, etc.

Comment: @0x5453 by "functions/macros" you mean lisp macros or keyboard macros? Keyboard macros are quite different from functions, which I think is the point of this answer.

Comment: @npostavs Fair, but I think a keyboard macro can just be defined as a list of commands, which by definition must be recursively composed of the same types of things.

Comment: @npostavs Though I will admit that the "Commands include strings" part is interesting; I'm not sure what a purely string command looks like or how it behaves.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :D never thought of doing this @Tyler

Comment: That's exactly what i thought and what lead me to doubt if this was correct thinking @0x5453

Comment: An example of a string (keyboard macro) command, bound to `C-c s`: `(global-set-key "\C-cs" "\C-x2\C-x3\C-x2\C-x3")` ... or written using `kbd` in each case (as I would normally do): `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c s") (kbd "C-x 2 C-x 3 C-x 2 C-x 3"))`

Comment: @0x5453 A keyboard macro could, hypothetically, be defined as a list of commands, but it isn't. It's defined as a sequence (specifically, a string or vector) of keys. You can observe this if you make keyboard macro, and then rebind one of the key bindings it uses.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think so. Every key is bound to a function. Actually, a command, which is an interactive function (meaning a function the user can call during editing, not just by running elisp code). Adding a letter to a file is accomplished via the command `self-insert`, which is bound to most unmodified keys by default.

I'm not sure how useful that is, but nearly every interaction you have with emacs is via a function.

Answer (score 2):

In the emacs lisp sense, not everything is a function.
*functionp* is a predicate to determine wether a symbol is bound to a function or not.

```
 (functionp 'set)
 t
 (functionp 'setq)
 nil
```

*set* is a built-in function writen in C, *setq* a special form which don't evaluate all its argument like functions does.

Comment: n.b. The OBJECT in `(functionp OBJECT)` needn't be a symbol.